# Online WYSIWYG editor, but output is for printing

Tags: pdf, printing, wysiwyg

I'm wondering whether there's any available web-based WYSIWYG editor, but the content will be saved and optimized for printing (using PDF).

I know it's possible to use stuff like FCK Editor and run a HTML to PDF converter, but the output sometimes is not satisfying.

Anyway, what format should I use to optimize for printing?

*p.s: I'm using .NET, but platform is not an issue.*

Answer (score 0):

You say, "sometimes is not satisfying": what's wrong with it?

Using a web editor you're printing HTML. Are you printing it on the server or on the client?

Perhaps you just need a better CSS with some additional optimizations/specializations for printing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a third part API like http://zoho.com